# in synfony4 How to force locale 'en' without taking the prefered language

Tags: locale, symfony4

in synfony4 i took the symfony demo app, and o want to know  How can I force defaultlocale to 'en' to my homepage without taking the prefered language of the browser 'fr'. I just want to keed the choice to change the language manually only

SERVICE.yaml

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
    # This parameter defines the codes of the locales (languages) enabled in the application
    app_locales: en|fr|de|es|cs|nl|ru|uk|ro|pt_BR|pl|it|ja|id|ca|sl|hr|zh_CN|bg|tr|lt
    app.notifications.email_sender: anonymous@example.com

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        bind:               # defines the scalar arguments once and apply them to any service defined/created in this file
            $locales: '%app_locales%'
            $defaultLocale: 'en'
            $emailSender: '%app.notifications.email_sender%'
```

FRAMEWORK.yaml

```
framework:
    default_locale: 'en'
```

I expected the first redirection will be 127.0.0.1:8000/en or 127.0.0.1:8000

But the actual output is 127.0.0.1:8000/fr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

I change this in the getpreferedLanguage method, it  works, it does what i expected.

```
if ($preferredLanguage !== $this->defaultLocale) {
    $response = new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('homepage', ['_locale' => 'en']));
    $event->setResponse($response); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just get rid of all the locales and the default locale parameters so in **services.yaml** you are left with:

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
    app.notifications.email_sender: anonymous@example.com

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        bind:               # defines the scalar arguments once and apply them to any service defined/created in this file
            $emailSender: '%app.notifications.email_sender%'
```

in **framework.yaml** you can simply remove the line.

When there is only one locale set there is no redirection to a locale, so will go to 127.0.0.1:8000 on the built-in server.

Comment: Thx you dirk for your response.
I did exactly what you said but now i 've got the message below:


Cannot autowire service "App\EventSubscriber\RedirectToPreferredLocaleSubscriber": argument "$locales" of method "__construct()" is type-hinted "string", you should configure its value explicitly.

Comment: You can remove RedirectToPreferredLocaleSubscriber.php and alse see if you might have other locale settings in the rest of your config like routes.yaml, security.yaml and annotations.yaml. Remove these or comment them out.

Comment: when i remove this file , the homepage is well to 127.0.0.1:8000 in english  but links to change the language give :http://127.0.0.1:8000/?_locale=fr